# How to dynamically insert an element on an element that was dynamically inserted?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to be able to dynamically append to an element that was dynamically appended.
If you have this:

```
<div id="main">

</div>

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#main').append('<div id="inner"></div>');

    $('#inner').append('<div id="goal"></div>');
});
```

`#goal` never gets appended. Is there a jquery function to handle this or how would I do it?

http://jsfiddle.net/jmZY4/

Comment: I can't do them together because I have a plugin that inserts one element, and then I want to insert an element in the first one through a call back.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turn it on its head ([live copy](http://jsfiddle.net/jmZY4/1/) — *there was a bug in the CSS of your example, btw, two `#main` rules and no `#inner` rule*):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var inner = $('<div id="inner"></div>');
    inner.appendTo('#main');
    inner.append('<div id="goal"></div>');
});
```

[`appendTo`](http://api.jquery.com/appendTo/) is kind of the converse of [`append`](http://api.jquery.com/append/).

You can write that more compactly, though (in my view) it's not worth the loss of clarity ([live copy](http://jsfiddle.net/jmZY4/2/)):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('<div id="inner"></div>')
        .appendTo('#main')
        .append('<div id="goal"></div>');
});
```

Of course, in your *precise* example, you could just ([live copy](http://jsfiddle.net/jmZY4/3/)):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#main').append('<div id="inner"><div id="goal"></div></div>');
});
```

...but I'm guessing you have a reason for doing the two separately.

Comment: oh it was a .css rule in my jsfiddle. Ok so if that does work, are any of you able to to solve my issue over here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6754251/need-help-with-twitter-widget. I'm having a hellofa time.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('<div id="inner"></div>').append('<div id="goal"></div>').appendTo('#main');
});
```